# How can I connect my HP Photosmart C3100 printer in 10.04 (regression from 9.x)

Tags: printing, hp

My printer was working under 9.x. It is a an HP Photosmart C3100 series. When I open Admin->Printing no local printers are found.

I try to add via *Other* (My local choices are Serial and other). I have tried many url's - `ipp://localhost:631/ipp`, `http://localhost/ipp`, `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, etc...  None have worked. Under the networked I have tried JetDirect, using localhost and 127.0.0.1 and port 631.

I have tried many options under IPP with different variants in the host trying to verify a printer. No luck .I tried LPD/LPR with localhost and tried the probe. no luck.
I tried the cups admin via localhost:631 and that didn't work. On the old version its simply found the local printer, I might have picked the driver, I can't remember but it was the photosmart c3100 series that was working.I just can't get 10.04 to print.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure your printer is turned on! And both the USB and power cables are securely connected.

As you are having problems I'd suggest you install the [HPLIP Toolbox](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/hplip-gui) - this software is created by Hewlett-Packard themselves.

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Once installed launch it from System->Preferences->HPLIP Toolkit. From here you should click on the green add button, and follow the instructions.

If all this still does not work then you should file a bug report. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `ubuntu-bug hplip`. In the bug description make sure you link to this question (and link from this question to the bug).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Printer is broken.  Won't work on Windows either.  Sorry for the time.